# What's the difference between generic_category and between system_category?

Tags: c++

I just used

```
system_error( error_code( (int)GetLastError(), system_category() ), "mystring" )
```

eception.what() internally uses FormatMessage() according to the eror-code on Windows, so everything seems to be fine. But am I right to use system_category() here or: what's the difference between system_category and generic_category?

[EDIT]: Is the error_category-object a mapper between the error-codes and the error-strings?

Answer (score 0):

Use...

- [`std::system_category()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_category) to mark errors relating to / originating from your *operating system*;
- [`std::generic_category()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/generic_category) for errors which can occur anywhere (like invalid argument, numeric value out of range, etc.), and are hence *generic*.
- Another, custom category if there's a whole, well, category of errors your program might generate which you want to bunch together conceptually.

To answer the second part of the question: Yes, an `std::error_category` object can "map" error codes to `std::error_condition`s. But - the error condition class is basically just a pair of a category and a code. So it's not much of a mapping.

Comment: This doesn't tell me what the error_category-object is used for when I catch the exception. As I added with EDIT above it seems to me that it is used to convert the error-code into an error string (error_category::message()).